# How to open XCSNAPSHOTS file or use it in a project

Tags: ios, xcode

I've renamed project and renamed folder to match new name and found that there are no snapshots any more (under all snapshots of Organizer - Projects). I have found the folder with snapshots and there is a file that starts with the old name of the project. How can I use this file as a snapshot destination? Is it possible?